# How to set up the LSTM network?

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am learning how to set up the RNN-LSTM network for prediction. I have created the dataset with one-variables.

```
x  y
1  2.5
2  6
3  8.6
4  11.2
5  13.8
6  16.4
...
```

And the relationship of the `y(t) = 2.5x(t) + x(t-1) -0.9*x(t-2)`. And I am trying to set up the RNN-LSTM to learn the pattern, but it occurred the error of my program. My program is like below:

```py
df= pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx')

def split_dataset(data):
    # split into standard weeks
    train, test = data[:-328], data[-328:-6]
    # restructure into windows of weekly data
    train = np.array(np.split(train, len(train)/1))
    test = np.array(np.split(test, len(test)/1))
    return train, test

verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 20, 16
train, test = split_dataset(df.values)
train_x, train_y = train[:,:,0], train[:,:,1]


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True, input_shape = train_x.shape))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

It occurred the `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_35_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8766, 1)
```

Any experienced DS or pythoner can teach me how to set up the network?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For LSTM based RNN, the input should be of 3 dimensions (batch, time, data_point). I assume index of your `x` variable is its time. In this case, you have to transform your input into batches of some window, say a window of 3, then your input is:

batch #         input        target

0        x[0:3]       y[3]

1          x[1:4]        y[4]

2          x[2:5]        y[5]

Note: your y's start from t=3 since you are using last 3 time steps to predict the next 4th value. If your y's are already calculated from the last three time steps as you have said, then y's should start from 0 index, i.e. at batch 0 you have y[0] as the target

**UPDATE** as per below comment 
If you want to have multiple sequences, then you can model it as a sequence to sequence problem and will be an `N to M` mapping, you need five x values to predict three y's:

batch #         input        target

0        x[0:5]       y[3:6]

1          x[1:6]        y[4:7]

2          x[2:7]        y[5:8]

Comment: It is work, but how to predict multi-step? Can you tell me more ? I have asked the question in above.

Comment: what do you mean by multi-step, could you pls elaborate?

Comment: base on (x(t),x(t-1)) to predict y(t), y(t+1)... or more , that means output is not only one value.

Comment: how about the code in python? How to write this in python LSTM setting? My above second reply has shown what I have tried and other questions.

Comment: you should not ask two question in one topic by creating two posts. can you please accept and upvote my answer and then create another question? Your first question has been answered and the second one needs another thread of its own.

Answer (score 0):

In current, I have created the data window and it look like work for I mentioned case.

Below is my code:

```py
df= pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx')

# split a univariate dataset into train/test sets
def split_dataset(data):
    train, test = data[:-328], data[-328:-6]
    return train, test

train, test  = split_dataset(df.values)

# scale train and test data to [-1, 1]
def scale(train, test):
    # fit scaler
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    scaler = scaler.fit(train)
    # transform train
    #train = train.reshape(train.shape[0], train.shape[1])
    train_scaled = scaler.transform(train)
    # transform test
    #test = test.reshape(test.shape[0], test.shape[1])
    test_scaled = scaler.transform(test)
    return scaler, train_scaled, test_scaled

scaler, train_scaled, test_scaled = scale(train, test)

def to_supervised(train, n_input, n_out=7):
    # flatten data
    data = train
    X, y = list(), list()
    in_start = 0
    # step over the entire history one time step at a time
    for _ in range(len(data)):
        # define the end of the input sequence
        in_end = in_start + n_input
        out_end = in_end + n_out
        # ensure we have enough data for this instance
        if out_end <= len(data):
            x_input = data[in_start:in_end, 0]
            x_input = x_input.reshape((len(x_input), 1))
            X.append(x_input)
            y.append(data[in_end:out_end, 0])
        # move along one time step
        in_start += 1
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)
train_x, train_y = to_supervised(train_scaled, n_input = 3, n_out = 1)
test_x, test_y =  to_supervised(test_scaled, n_input = 3, n_out = 1)

verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 20, 16
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2], train_y.shape[1]


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences= False, input_shape = (train_x.shape[1],train_x.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'adam')
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose, validation_data = (test_x, test_y))
```

However, I have other questions about this:

Q1: What is the meaning of units in LSTM? [model.add(LSTM(`units`, ...))]

(I have tried different units for the model, it would be more accurate as units increased.)

Q2: How many layers should I set?

Q3: How can I predict multi-steps ? e.g base on (x(t),x(t-1)) to predict y(t), y(t+1)
I have tried to set the `n_out = 2` in the `to_supervised` function, but when I applied the same method, it returned the error

```
train_x, train_y = to_supervised(train_scaled, n_input = 3, n_out = 2)
test_x, test_y =  to_supervised(test_scaled, n_input = 3, n_out = 2)

verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 20, 16
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2], train_y.shape[1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences= False, input_shape = (train_x.shape[1],train_x.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'adam')
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose, validation_data = (test_x, test_y))
```

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_27 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

Q3(cont): What should I add or change in the model setting?

Q3(cont): What is the `return_sequences` ? When should I set `True`?

Comment: good, create another thread and then send me a link, I will try to answer it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004563/how-to-set-up-lstm-network-for-predict-multi-sequence